# How does one enable Developer Options on an HTC One?

Tags: android, configuration, remote-debugging, htc-android

I am trying to set up remote debugging on an HTC One.

On the Android web site, and the Marmalade web site, they say I need to "enable on-device developer options", but I have not found Developer Options on my phone as instructed.

They write:

> To access these settings, open the Developer options in the system Settings. On Android 4.2 and higher, the Developer options screen is hidden by default. To make it visible, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options at the bottom.

Well, on my HTC One (running Android version 4.4.2), the closest thing I have to "Settings > About phone > Build Number" is "Settings > About > Software version", and clicking it seven times does nothing at all.

How can I enable Developer Options?

Comment: It's build number, not software version.

Comment: Yep, but on the first dozen or so times I looked, the closest thing I found was Software version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in the process of typing this in, I found where it is. It's:

Settings > About > Software information > More > Build number

And that DOES respond to clicking seven times.

Hopefully, this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

1) Download HTC Sync Manager
http://www.htc.com/us/support/software/htc-sync-manager.aspx

2) Then you need to download the "USB Driver" for the particular phone you have. So for the HTC One M9 Phone I have, I had to download the HTC USB Drivers from here:
http://www.theandroidsoul.com/download-htc-one-m9-drivers-for-windows-adb-fastboot-74714/

3) Turn on "USB Debugging" for you phone.
For the HTC One M9, go to

Settings -> About->Software Information->More->Build Number

Click Build Number 7 times until it says that you are a developer.

Then go to

Settings-> Developer Options -> Make sure "USB Debugging" is checked.

4) Plug your phone into your laptop and run your app from Android Studio.

Comment: It adds some information, but not a lot. Just leave the answer but don't vote it up.